# How to add admin user to existing postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

We have an existing postgres database `gsrdb` in production with **superuser** `gsr`. We have been doing all the database maintenance with that user `gsr`. Also, the same user `gsr` is used by our app service to do transactions on the database.

We want to change this now. We want a separate superuser `gsr_admin`(whose credentials are managed by Vault) that can do the dba maintenance but still have our app service use existing user `gsr`.

The problem I am facing is that all the database objects so far are owned by `gsr` user and if I run updates, as user `gsr_admin`, on the database w.r.t. either table constraints or sequences it fails saying `error: must be owner of relation...blah blah`

How can I fix this?

So I was thinking if I could create a **superuser admin group role** called `admin_group` and reassign all the ownerships of all the database objects to it from user `gsr` and then alter both users `gsr` and `gsr_admin` to belong to this admin group role. Wouldn't that way everything that has been created so far would be owned by role `admin_group` ? And whether I create new objects as a user `gsr` or as `gsr_admin` either of them can still update the objects?

I might be wrong. Would really appreciate some inputs.

Comment: I think I can do this by creating a `superuser admin role` say `proxy_admin`. And then I change the ownership of all the database objects to `proxy_admin` and then whenever `gsr` or `gsr_admin` logs in I set the role to `proxy_admin`. 

I don't know how to do this though. Would appreciate some inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run

```
ALTER ROLE gsr NOSUPERUSER;
ALTER ROLE gsr RENAME TO gsr_admin;  -- needs a new password now
CREATE ROLE gsr LOGIN;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA myschema TO gsr;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
   ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myschema TO gsr;
```

Similarly, grant `USAGE` on sequences and other required privileges. You may want to run some `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` for future objects as well.